# What does the phrase by Sloterdijk mean?

Tags: vocabulary

"A session of a carnival club" - what's that? What kind of club is it? Any synonyms? Descroptions? Examples? Anything?

Comment: A club that organizes a yearly carnival celebration

Comment: Is it something like when folks gather in a community center, drink tea and talk about where to put "the best apple pie tent", and when's the best date for the carnival, etc. Just like that?

Comment: When did this become an English word?

Comment: Can you give more context? Who is Sloterdijk? What kind of carnivals is he concerned with? Can you geive the context or the passage in which this phrase appears?

Comment: [Source:](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+session+of+a+carnival%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) *but [youth camp rituals and midsummer feasts] have no more spiritual weight than, let's say, the opening ceremonies of a sports festival or the **session of a carnival club***. Looks like basic English (General Reference) to me, even if the usage isn't exactly "widespread" for making such comparisons.

Comment: It appears that Peter Sloterdijk writes in German, exclusively or nearly so. I suspect this is a poorly translated idiom that can't be analyzed here.

Answer (score 2):

A carnival club is a civic organization (probably in a Catholic community) that organizes a float for the carnival parade that celebrates the beginning of Lent.  They are similar to the Mardi Gras Krewes of New Orleans.   Sloterdijk was a German philosopher and there is a suburb of Amsterdam with this name.  It is not likely that there is a carnival crew in modern day Sloterdijk as there is not an existing carnival tradition in that city that I am aware of.  It is more likely that this is some reference to writings by the man Sloterdijk on this subject.

Comment: I misunderstood the relationship between the heading and the subtext.  Misreading the question to be What does the phrase "by Sloterkijk" mean? I was not trying to be snarky.  Oops.

Comment: [Source](http://www.tabvlarasa.de/20/sorgner.php) The old carnival was a substitute revolution for the poor. A kingly fool was elected who reigned over a thoroughly inverted world for a day and a night. In this inverted world, the poor and the decent brought their dreams to life, as costumed oafs and bacchanals, forgetting themselves to the point of truth, cheeky, lewd, turbulent, and disgraceful. ... Class societies can scarcely survive without the institution of the inverted world and the crazy day - as Brazilian carnivals demonstrate.